# Decorating Hex function to pad zeros

Tags: python, hex, padding, built-in

I wrote this simple function:

```
def padded_hex(i, l):
    given_int = i
    given_len = l

    hex_result = hex(given_int)[2:] # remove '0x' from beginning of str
    num_hex_chars = len(hex_result)
    extra_zeros = '0' * (given_len - num_hex_chars) # may not get used..

    return ('0x' + hex_result if num_hex_chars == given_len else
            '?' * given_len if num_hex_chars > given_len else
            '0x' + extra_zeros + hex_result if num_hex_chars < given_len else
            None)
```

Examples:

```
padded_hex(42,4) # result '0x002a'
hex(15) # result '0xf'
padded_hex(15,1) # result '0xf'
```

Whilst this is clear enough for me and fits my use case (a simple test tool for a simple printer) I can't help thinking there's a lot of room for improvement and this could be squashed down to something very concise.

What other approaches are there to this problem?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Starting with Python 3.6, you can:

```
>>> value = 42
>>> padding = 6
>>> f"{value:#0{padding}x}"
'0x002a'
```

---

for older python versions use the [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) string method:

```
>>> "{0:#0{1}x}".format(42,6)
'0x002a'
```

**Explanation:**

```
{   # Format identifier
0:  # first parameter
#   # use "0x" prefix
0   # fill with zeroes
{1} # to a length of n characters (including 0x), defined by the second parameter
x   # hexadecimal number, using lowercase letters for a-f
}   # End of format identifier
```

If you want the letter hex digits uppercase but the prefix with a lowercase 'x', you'll need a slight workaround:

```
>>> '0x{0:0{1}X}'.format(42,4)
'0x002A'
```

Comment: Is it possible to write this as a format string in python 3.6?

Comment: Yes, but without any success, since I cannot figure out the correct syntax for it: `value = 42; padding = 6; f"{value:#0{padding}x}"` throws a syntax error: `  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f"{value:#0{padding}x}"
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: This works for me on Python 3.6.4. Try `import sys; print(sys.version)` to make sure you're running the correct interpreter.

Comment: python really likes to complicate things up

Comment: Can I have a lowercase 'x' with an upper case hex, like `0x002A` with this format solution?

Comment: @Katu: You can do `f"{value:#0{padding}X}".replace("X","x")`

Comment: Sorry... None of what I read here works for negative numbers...
Try this instead: val = 42
nbits = 16
"{:0>4s}".format(hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))[2:]).upper()

Answer (score 38):

How about this:

```
print '0x%04x' % 42
```

Comment: use the `*` to pass width: `'0x%0*x' % (4,42)
`

Answer (score 37):

If you don't need to handle negative numbers, you can do

```
"{:02x}".format(7)   # '07'
"{:02x}".format(27)  # '1b'
```

Where

- `:` is the start of the [formatting specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for the first argument `{}` to `.format()`
- `02` means "pad the input from the left with `0`s to length `2`"
- `x` means "format as hex with lowercase letters"

You can also do this with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
f"{7:02x}"   # '07'
f"{27:02x}"  # '1b'
```

Answer (score 20):

If just for leading zeros, you can try `zfill` function.

```
'0x' + hex(42)[2:].zfill(4) #'0x002a'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `*` to pass width and `X` for uppercase

```
print '0x%0*X' % (4,42) # '0x002A'
```

As suggested by [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638449/604004) and [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary)

Comment: What is the reason to use * to pass width?

Comment: @RafaelJ To make it generic, instead of having it hardcoded

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hold the preceding hex notation `0x` you can also try this method too which is using the python3 [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).

```
    f'0x{10:02x}' # 0x0a
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers are dealing well with negative numbers...
Try this:

```
val = 42
nbits = 16
'{:04X}'.format(val & ((1 << nbits)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: ```'{:0{}X}'.format(val & ((1 << nbits)-1), int((nbits+3)/4))``` will set the width correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to have leading zeros for hexadecimal number, for example you want 7 digit where your hexadecimal number should be written on,  you can do like that :

```
hexnum = 0xfff
str_hex =  hex(hexnum).rstrip("L").lstrip("0x") or "0"
'0'* (7 - len(str_hexnum)) + str_hexnum
```

This gives as a result :

```
'0000fff'
```

Comment: `'%0*x' % (7,0xfff)`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a random HexDec String [000001 - FFFFFF]:

```
# !/usr/bin/python39
import random

f'{random.randint(1, 16777215):06x}'.upper()
```