# Python Hexadecimal

Tags: python, hex

How to convert decimal to hex in the following format (at least two digits, zero-padded, without an 0x prefix)?

Input: `255`    Output:`ff`

Input: `2`       Output: `02`

I tried `hex(int)[2:]` but it seems that it displays the first example but not the second one.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: I tried hex(int)[2:] but it seems that it displays the first example but not the second one.

Comment: The question and the answers are less useful without an explicit statement of what specifically "the following format" means. Probably "at least two digits, zero-padded, without an 0x prefix"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorating Hex function to pad zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638408/decorating-hex-function-to-pad-zeros)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) with a `'02x'` format.

```
>>> format(255, '02x')
'ff'
>>> format(2, '02x')
'02'
```

The `02` part tells `format()` to use at least 2 digits and to use zeros to pad it to length, `x` means lower-case hexadecimal.

The [*Format Specification Mini Language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) also gives you `X` for uppercase hex output, and you can prefix the field width with `#` to include a `0x` or `0X` prefix (depending on wether you used `x` or `X` as the formatter). Just take into account that you need to adjust the field width to allow for those extra 2 characters:

```
>>> format(255, '02X')
'FF'
>>> format(255, '#04x')
'0xff'
>>> format(255, '#04X')
'0XFF'
```

Comment: I'm having an issue where the hexadecimal prefix will have a capital "X" if set the format to use uppercase hex output. This doesn't seem to be the case in your example. Is this just an issue with my local version of Python? I'm using version 2.7.9.

Comment: @jwp36: no, it was a mistake in my answer, now corrected. My apologies.

Comment: to specify the format in the output string `'{:02x}'.format(255)`

Comment: @JuanPablo: only do that in a *larger string*. Using `str.format()` just to have it parse out a single slot is making Python do extra work (as internally this still uses `format(255, '02x')` for that one slot).

Answer (score 26):

I think this is what you want:

```
>>> def twoDigitHex( number ):
...     return '%02x' % number
... 
>>> twoDigitHex( 2 )
'02'
>>> twoDigitHex( 255 )
'ff'
```

Answer (score -8):

Another solution is:

```
>>> "".join(list(hex(255))[2:])
'ff'
```

Probably an archaic answer, but functional.

Comment: In the same vein as another answer, this does not zero pad.  For example, `"".join(list(hex(2))[2:])` evaluates to `'2'`, not `'02'`.

Comment: This is synonymous with `hex(int)[2:]` from the question. Why do you make a list just to join it again?

Comment: Why post this answer if you already agree that there is a better one?