# How to add string representation of hex?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of hex as strings.

```
str = "e79"     # 0xe79
str2 = "1533a"  # 0x1533a
etc...
```

What's the best way to do some addition on these? For example, if I have *str = "e79"* and I want to add the decimal 37 to it to get *str = "e9e"*

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type.

Comment: Sorry, I was just using that a quick example. Thanks for your answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to parse the values into integers if you want to do integer arithmetic; use `int(hexstring, 16)`.

You can always convert back to the hex string representation [using `format()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal):

```
result = format(int(strvalue, 16) + 37, 'x')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    result = hex(int(str, 16) + int(str2, 16))
```

Comment: `hex()` should only be used if you want to produce Python's *hex literal notation*, which includes a `0x` prefix.