# How to print hex dump from a buffer in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python snippet like this:

```
siz=len(ret)
for i in range(0,siz-1):
       print "%s " % ret[i],
```

When I use `%s` it works fine and prints some alien characters on the console!!

But how do I print hex dump of it.

I tried:

```
print "%02x " % ret[i],

print "%02x " % hex(ret[i]),

print format(ret[i],'02x'),

print format(hex(ret[i],'02x'),

print "%02x " % hex(int(ret[i])),
```

All these things resulted in errors.

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal) but those answers didn't help me.

How do I do this similar to `c` style `printf("%02x ",ret[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the character code which you can obtain with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), then you can apply your method to print the character code hexadecimal:

```
ret="#~½|"
for c in ret:
   print "%s  -  %02x" % (c,ord(c))
```

Which gives as output:

```
#  -  23
~  -  7e
�  -  c2
�  -  bd
|  -  7c
4  -  34
```