# Python - text file with all values 0 to 2^24 in HEX

Tags: python

I am trying to create a file with all possible values for 0 up to 2^24 in HEX.

This is what I have so far:

```
file_name = "values.txt"
counter = 0
value = 0x0000000000
with open (file_name, 'w') as writer:
    while counter < 16777216:
        data_to_write = str(value) + '\n' 
        writer.write(data_to_write)
        counter = counter + 1
        value = value + 0x0000000001
```

This do what I want but with integers. Is there an easy way to turn this to HEX values in file instead (still as string)?

Thank you

Comment: "all possible values for 2^2" - you're going to have to explain what you mean by that. I only see two possible values for 2^2: 0, if ^ is XOR, or 4, if ^ is exponentiation. You seem to be trying to say something completely different.

Comment: I tried: data_to_write = str(hex(value)) + '\n'

But then I get 0x first, so then I need to remove that somehow...

Comment: 0 up to 2^24  :-) Sorry

Comment: Did you mean 2^24-1?

Comment: @Matrilx Then try `hex(value)[2:]`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Hexadecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

just use the format method from string when writting:

```
writer.write("{:#X}".format(data_to_write))
```

Example:

```
>>> "{:#x}".format(123324)
'0x1e1bc'
>>> "{:#X}".format(123324)
'0X1E1BC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

It is working now:

```
file_name = "value.txt"
counter = 0
value = 0x0000000000
with open (file_name, 'w') as writer:
    while counter < 10000:
        data_to_write = str(hex(value)[2:].zfill(6)) + '\n' 
        writer.write(data_to_write)
        counter = counter + 1
        value = value + 0x0000000001
```

Comment: You could use `"{:010x}".format(value)` for a bit more readability.