# Remove 0x from Hex String

Tags: python

```
val1 = hex(100)
val2 = hex(50)
val3 = hex(int(val1, 16) - int(val2, 16))

hex_str = str(val1) + str(val2) + str(val3)

print(hex_str)
```

In the above example, my end goal is to have a string that looks like this: `643232`

Currently however the result I am getting has the string as `0x640x320x32`

Is there a way in Python to remove the `0x` from the beginning of a hex string?

Or will I have to remove it using a regular expression with something like `re.sub()`?

EDIT: I also need to make sure I am always getting too characters.  So for example if I was looking for the hex value of 5 I'd get `05`

Comment: `val1 = hex(100)[2:]`

Comment: Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: In Python3.6: `val1 = f'{100:x}'`

Comment: @Skitzafreak> full code with string formatting: `"{:x}{:x}{:x}".format(val1, val2, val3)`.

Comment: How do I make it so I will always have 2 characters?  See my edit above

Comment: Change the format specifier from `x` to `02x` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678150/1322401) to [python hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal).  So `format(3, '02x')` would give you `'03'`.  "The `02` part tells `format()` to use at least 2 digits and to use zeros to pad it to length, `x` means lower-case hexadecimal."  For your last operation your format would be `"{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(100, 50, 50)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary [python hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal) is a better duplicate since the OP wants pad single digit results with a leading zero.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Done!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
val1 = hex(100)[2:]
val2 = hex(50)[2:]
val3 = hex(int(val1, 16) - int(val2, 16))[2:]

hex_str = str(val1) + str(val2) + str(val3)

print(hex_str)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know you could do the `[2:]` thing at the end of `hex()`

Comment: Don't do that. Use the correct tools for the job, python string formatting. That is: `"{:x}".format(100)`

Comment: @spectras Or simply `format(100, 'x')`.

Comment: Whichever you like the most :). The point being no convert-to-undesired-format-then-mangle-the-output, that's just wasting resources.