# Python convert a string containing hex to actual hex

Tags: python, hex, decimal, implicit-conversion

I have a *hex string*, but i need to convert it to *actual* *hex*.
For example, i have this *hex string*:

```
3f4800003f480000
```

One way I could achieve my goal is by using escape sequences:

```
print("\x3f\x48\x00\x00\x3f\x48\x00\x00")
```

However, I can't do it this way, because I want create together my hex from multiple variables.

My program's ***purpose*** is to:

1. take in a number for instance `100`
2. multiply it by `100`: `100 * 100 = 10000`
3. convert it to hex `2710`
4. add `0000`
5. add `2710` again
6. add `0000` once more

**Result** I'm expecting is `2710000027100000`. Now I need to pass this hexadecimal number as argument to a function (as hexadecimal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal)

Comment: in this question they want to cnvert a decimal to a hexadecimal, but i have a string already containing hexadecimals

Comment: If you multiply by 6553600 instead of by 100, you are halfway to your target without any string manipulations. But your ultimate program's purpose is not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, there is no separate type as 'hex'. It represents the hexadecimal notation of the number as `str`. You may check the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) yourself by calling it on [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) as:

```
#         v  convert integer to hex
>>> type(hex(123))
<type 'str'>
```

But in order to represent the value as a hexadecimal, Python prepends the `0x` to the string which represents *hexadecimal* number. For example:

```
>>> hex(123)
'0x7b'
```

So, in your case in order to display your string as a hexadecimal equivalent, all you need is to prepend it with "0x" as:

```
>>> my_hex = "0x" + "3f4800003f480000"
```

This way if you probably want to later convert it into some other notation, let's say integer *(which based on the nature of your problem statement, you'll definitely need)*, all you need to do is call `int` with **base** 16 as:

```
>>> int("0x3f4800003f480000", base=16)
4559894623774310400
```

In fact Python's interpreter is smart enough. If you won't even prepend "0x", it will take care of it. For example:

```
>>> int("3f4800003f480000", base=16)
4559894623774310400
```

"0x" is all about representing the string is hexadecimal string in case someone is looking/debugging your code (in future), they'll get the idea. That's why it is preferred.

***So my suggestion is to stick with Python's Hex styling, and don't convert it with escape characters as "\x3f\x48\x00\x00\x3f\x48\x00\x00"***

---

From the [Python's `hex` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) :

> Convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”. If x is not a Python int object, it has to define an **index**() method that returns an integer.

Answer (score 2):

try `binascii.unhexlify`:

> Return the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string hexstr.

example:

```
assert binascii.unhexlify('3f4800003f480000') == b"\x3f\x48\x00\x00\x3f\x48\x00\x00"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> hex(int('3f4800003f480000', 16))
'0x3f4800003f480000'
```