# How to realize Ansible nested loop for nested 3 lvl dictionary

Tags: ansible

I faced with task to implement nested loop for Ansible.
Example:

I have below playbook:

```yaml
- name: Combine dictionaries based on matching values
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    dict1:
      group1:
        -
          "id": 1
          "var1": "var1_value"
          "var2": "var2_value"
          "var3": "var3_value"
        -
          "id": 2
          "var1": "var1_value"
          "var2": "var2_value"
          "var3": "var3_value"
      group2:
        -
          "id": 3
          "var1": "var1_value"
          "var2": "var2_value"
          "var3": "var3_value"

    dict2:
      "dict2_data":
        "data":
          - 
            "var1": "var1_value"
            "var2": "var2_value"
            "var3": "var3_value"
          - 
            "var1": "var1_value"
            "var2": "var2_value"
            "var3": "var3_value"

tasks:
```

I need to compare vars from `dict2.dict2_data.data.*` with each `dict1.group*.vars`, and if `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are the same, to do something.

The count of items in both dicts are unlimited.

The expression I expected is nested loop like:

```py
for item0 in dict1:
  for item1 in item0:
    for item2 in dict2["dict2_data"]["data"]:
      if item1["var1"] == item2["var1"] and item1["var3"] == item2["var3"]:
         print("True")
```

I got a solution, but it's dirty:

1. I converted items2dict.
2. Then I created Ansible loop with tasks include_task, and in new file I added new loop with include_task.
   It means that each loop is a new file.
   That resolve my task, but it's too complicated.

I need more easy way. Any thoughts?

Comment: `I need more easy way. Any thoughts?` => create a custom filter and do the job in python directly. For a quick example of what a custom filter looks like, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66665171/9401096. If you want to stick to "pure" ansible, the solution you found is actually pretty much the best you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the dictionaries for testing, the first item of *group1* matches the second item of *data*

```yaml
  dict1:
    group1:
      - {id: 1, var1: x1, var2: x2, var3: x3}
      - {id: 2, var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: v3}
    group2:
      - {id: 3, var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: v3}

  dict2:
    data:
      - {var1: d1, var2: d2, var3: d3}
      - {var1: x1, var2: x2, var3: x3}
```

In the loop, get the [*symmetric_difference*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) length of the values,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for d in dict2.data %}
          {% set d_index=loop.index %}
          {% set _keys=d.keys()|list %}
          {% set _data=d.values()|list %}
          {% for group,ids in dict1.items() %}
          {% for i in ids %}
          {% set _vals=_keys|map('extract', i)|list %}
          {% set diff=_vals|symmetric_difference(_data)|length %}
          data_{{ d_index }} {{ group }}_{{ i.id }} {{ _vals }} {{ _data }} {{ diff }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    data_1 group1_1 ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'] 6
    data_1 group1_2 ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'] ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'] 6
    data_1 group2_3 ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'] ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'] 6
    data_2 group1_1 ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] 0
    data_2 group1_2 ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'] ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] 6
    data_2 group2_3 ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'] ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] 6
```

If this is working as expected declare the variable *result*

```yaml
    result: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for d in dict2.data %}
      {% set d_index=loop.index %}
      {% set _keys=d.keys()|list %}
      {% set _data=d.values()|list %}
      {% for group,ids in dict1.items() %}
      {% for i in ids %}
      {% set _vals=_keys|map('extract', i)|list %}
      {% set diff=_vals|symmetric_difference(_data)|length %}
      data_{{ d_index }} {{ group }}_{{ i.id }}: {{ diff|ternary(false, true) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    data_1 group1_1: false
    data_1 group1_2: false
    data_1 group2_3: false
    data_2 group1_1: true
    data_2 group1_2: false
    data_2 group2_3: false
```

Write report

```yaml
   - debug:
        msg: "The values of {{ item.key|split|first }} and {{ item.key|split|last }} match."
      loop: "{{ result|dict2items|selectattr('value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: The values of data_2 and group1_1 match.
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dict1:
      group1:
        - {id: 1, var1: x1, var2: x2, var3: x3}
        - {id: 2, var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: v3}
      group2:
        - {id: 3, var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: v3}

    dict2:
      data:
        - {var1: d1, var2: d2, var3: d3}
        - {var1: x1, var2: x2, var3: x3}

    result: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for d in dict2.data %}
      {% set d_index=loop.index %}
      {% set _keys=d.keys()|list %}
      {% set _data=d.values()|list %}
      {% for group,ids in dict1.items() %}
      {% for i in ids %}
      {% set _vals=_keys|map('extract', i)|list %}
      {% set diff=_vals|symmetric_difference(_data)|length %}
      data_{{ d_index }} {{ group }}_{{ i.id }}: {{ diff|ternary(false, true) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for d in dict2.data %}
          {% set d_index=loop.index %}
          {% set _keys=d.keys()|list %}
          {% set _data=d.values()|list %}
          {% for group,ids in dict1.items() %}
          {% for i in ids %}
          {% set _vals=_keys|map('extract', i)|list %}
          {% set diff=_vals|symmetric_difference(_data)|length %}
          data_{{ d_index }} {{ group }}_{{ i.id }} {{ _vals }} {{ _data }} {{ diff }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: result

    - debug:
        msg: "The values of {{ item.key|split|first }} and {{ item.key|split|last }} match."
      loop: "{{ result|dict2items|selectattr('value') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for example, but I know that approach. I can't simplify the data, so I need lvl3 nested dict and compare with lvl2 nested dict.

Comment: In the declaration of the `result`, change `dict2.data` to `dict2.dict2_data.data`. The result will be the same.