# Python How to use hex() to add zeros to the beginning until it has the required amount of characters?

Tags: python-3.x, hex

Let's say:

```
hex(89)
```

will return

```
0x59
```

Is it possible somehow to make it always return a 4 character string? I need it as 0x0059, not 0x59. Also, if the result is 0x67F for example, I need it as 0x067F and if it already is 4 characters after 0x then no zeros need to be added.
How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorating Hex function to pad zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638408/decorating-hex-function-to-pad-zeros)

Comment: Please check the options already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638408/decorating-hex-function-to-pad-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple case like yours might be enough to do:

```
decimal_num = 89
f"0x{decimal_num:04x}"
"0x{:04x}".format(decimal_num)
```

Apart from the official string formatting info, there is some examples in https://pyformat.info/