# Can f-strings auto-pad to [the next] even number of digits on output?

Tags: python, hex, f-string

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552797/10761353) (among others) it seems like f-strings is [one of] the preferred ways to convert to hexadecimal representation.

While one can specify an explicit target length, up to which to pad with leading zeroes, **given a goal of an output with an even number of digits**, and inputs with an arbitrary # of bits, I can imagine:

- pre-processing to determine the number of bits of the input, to feed an input-specific value in to the fstring, or
- post-processing a-la `out = "0"+f"{val:x}" if len(f"{val:x}") % 2 else f"{val:02x}"` (or even using `.zfill()`)

The latter seems like it might be more efficient than the former - is there a built-in way to do this with fstrings, or a better alternative?

Examples of input + expected output:

```
[0x]1 -> [0x]01
[0x]22 -> [0x]22
[0x]333 -> [0x]0333
[0x]4444 -> [0x]4444
```

and so on.

Comment: do you mean take in something like 0x333 and output 0x0333 because that is the next closest even number of digits?

Comment: exactly. `[0x]333` -> `[0x]0333` or `[0x]55555` -> `[0x]055555` and so on

Comment: So then that also means that 0x33 would return 0x33, correct?

Comment: That is the expectation, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a postprocessing alternative that uses assignment expressions (Python 3.8+):

```
print((len(hx:=f"{val:x}") % 2) * '0' + hx)
```

If you still want a one-liner without assignment expressions you have to evaluate your f-string twice:

```
print((len(f"{val:x}") % 2) * '0' + f"{val:x}")
```

As a two-liner

```
hx = f"{val:x}"
print((len(hx) % 2) * '0' + hx)
```

And one more version:

```
print(f"{'0'[:len(hex(val))%2]}{val:x}")
```

Comment: Awarding the answer here for the `len(fstr) % 2 * "0"` post-processing variant - a little cleaner than my one-line `if`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built in to f-string formatting that will do this. You probably have to figure out what the "natural" width would be then round that up to the next even number.

Something like this:

```
def hf(n):
    width = len(hex(n)) - 2 # account for leading 0x
    width += width % 2 # round up
    return f'{n:0{width}x}'

print(hf(1))
print(hf(15))
print(hf(16))
print(hf(255))
print(hf(256))
```

**Output:**

```
01
0f
10
ff
0100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in the pad-length part of the f-string. For example:

```
n = 4
val = 257
print(f"{val:0{n}x}") # 0101
```

Now, to figure out how many hex characters are in an integer, you just need to find how many bits are in the integer:

```
hex_count, rem = divmod(max(1, val.bit_length()), 4)
hex_count += (rem > 0)
```

(`max(1, val.bit_length())` handles the case where `val == 0`, which has a bit length of 0)

So let's get the next even number after `hex_count`:

```
pad_length = hex_count + (hex_count % 2)
print(f"{val:0{pad_length}x}") # 0101
```

I'm not sure if this is any better than simply converting it to a hex string and then figuring out how much padding is needed, but I can't think of a readable way to do this all in an f-string. An *unreadable* way would be by combining all of the above into a single line, but IMO readable code is better than unreadable one-liners. I don't think there's a way to specify what you want as a simple f-string.

Note that negative numbers are formatted to an even number of digits, plus the `-` sign.

Answer (score -1):

off topic:

to format a bytestring to an even number of hex digits:

```
import binascii
binascii.b2a_hex(b"\x00\x01\x02\x03").decode("ascii")
```

or

```
import base64 
base64.b16encode(b"\x00\x01\x02\x03").decode("ascii")
```

or

```
"".join(map(lambda b: f"{b:02x}", b"\x00\x01\x02\x03"))
```

or

```
"".join(map("{0:02x}".format, b"\x00\x01\x02\x03"))
```

Comment: Thanks @milahu, but that doesn't accomplish the goal - it actually adds extra zeroes in the middle, changing the values: `for digits in ["1", "22", "333", "4444"]:
...  "".join(map(lambda b: f"{b:02x}", [int(d) for d in digits]))` -> `'01', '0202', '030303', '04040404'`

Comment: no. the integer values are limited to the range from 0 to 255. these are bytes. i have replaced the integer arrays with bytestrings. `list(b"\x00\x01\x02\x03") == [0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: I fail to see how working with bytes helps to prepend the correct # of `0` to a hex number, so there is an even number of digits (as in OP)

Comment: aah, my bad, i failed to read the question. this popped up in search results. my goal was to format a bytestring to an even number of hex digits, so my answer is off topic